# Using text/event-stream in Intellij HTTP Client

Tags: intellij-idea

I have Spring based Java application with a REST controller which returns Project-Reactor's `Flux` type.
The `MediaType` this GET endpoint returns is `TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE`.

To be clearer on the matter, the endpoint looks a little as follows, omitting the actual operation to return as it's not important:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/sample", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Sample> getSampleFlux() {
    return /* A Flux containing Sample */
}
```

This bit of code works, as when I call it from my code or through for example Chrome using the endpoint, the results are streamed through as desired.

However, I wanted to test this behavior with [Intellij's HTTP Client](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html).
To this end, I created the following operation in a `*.http` file in my project:

```
GET localhost:8080/sample
Accept: text/event-stream
###
```

Running it works from within Intellij, but nothing is returned, ever.

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?
I am likely wrongfully using the HTTP Client, but I can't find any clear samples from other people trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it was fixed in 2021.3:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239328